# 2008 R2 bare metal V2V restore from USB in HyperV

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v

need to do a bare metal restore of a 2008R2 HyperV guest. Windows Backup is on USB. The HypeV host where the new VM is setup is 2012 R2.

Started new VM and passed through the USB drive but the restore tool cannot see the drive. When I open a command prompt and run diskpart from the 2008R2 boot disk, I do not see the disk but in the VM settings I can see the disk is connected.

Do I need to load the virutal scsi controller drivers? I tried but it doesn't find anything in the guest CD either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to mark offline the USB drive on the Hyper-V host (using the disk management or diskpart) and then pass through the entire physical disk to the VM. This article will come in handy:

https://redmondmag.com/articles/2018/05/17/usb-passthrough-in-hyperv.aspx